# Set Atom editor file type to 'plain text' if no extension

Tags: file, text, atom-editor

I often do not add a .txt extension to plain text files that are "notes".

In the past Atom had no problem with this, auto-detecting them as plain text, but a recent update made these appear as YAML!

Is there a way to set files with no extension to plain text?

Comment: [This](https://discuss.atom.io/t/change-syntax-highlighting-based-on-file-extension/6262) might help out.

Comment: I have the latest atom and the latest language packages and this does not happen to me. You must have done something custom in your settings.

Comment: Just turning yaml off worked. But still, that's not an answer to the question. I do believe there's a change that snuck in. Or maybe I changed a setting, but I don't recall doing that recently.